# WebSocket client disconnect due to network loss doesn't get intercepted by Spring server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-websocket

I have an application in which clients use websockets to connect to a server which is running Spring Boot Tomcat. 
My question is if there is a way for the server to detect a client disconnect due to a network loss.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using stomp , check SessionDisconnectEvent.
For raw Websocket connections, you can use : 
WebSocketHandler-->afterConnectionClosed

Comment: I'm not using stomp. The afterConnectionClosed method from  WebSocketHandler doesn't get triggered when a client looses it's internet connection.

Comment: did you check -> handleTransportError  method ?

Comment: handleTransportError should be triggered but you should identify the exception . if it is a websocket disconnection type of exception, you can fire your event..

Comment: handleTransportError gets triggered only after sending some messages through the websocket to the disconnected client and only after 6-7 minutes, so the messages sent get lost. Do you have any idea of why handleTransportError gets trigger with such delay after writing to the websocket?

Comment: handleTransportError is being  caled when all kind of websocket connection problems occured, not waiting anything. 6-7 minute is too long, are you set ServletServerContainerFactoryBean.setMaxSessionIdleTimeout ?
By the way, Tomcat or your proxy can close the websocket session if the tcp connection has been idle for more than Tomcat or Proxy Idle seconds.You need both ping-pong mechanism and websocket connection lost controls.

Comment: I'm not setting ServletServerContainerFactoryBean.setMaxSessionIdleTimeout. Do you know how Tomcat idle seconds could be set?

Comment: i guess it is : <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>

Comment: I've added 'server.session.timeout' property in application.properties file  and set it to value 30 but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

I have searched before for this and the solution I was able to find was to implement a ping-pong mechanism between the server and the clients.

For example, each few seconds send a dummy message to the client on a specific topic and receive back another dummy reply, if you didn't get a reply for a configured period you can consider the client disconnected.

As mentioned [here](http://www.theotherian.com/2014/03/spring-boot-websockets-stomp-chat.html),

> STOMP and Spring also allow us to set up topics, where every
>   subscriber will receive the same message. This is going to be very
>   useful for tracking active users. In the UI, each user subscribes to a
>   topic that reports back which users are active, and in our example
>   that topic will produce a message every 2 seconds. The client will
>   reply to every message containing a list of users with its own
>   heartbeat, which then updates the message being sent to other clients.
>   If a client hasn't checked in for more than 5 seconds (i.e. missed two
>   heartbeats), we consider them offline. This gives us near real time
>   resolution of users being available to chat. Users will appear in a
>   box on the left hand side of the screen, clicking on a name will pull
>   up a chat window for them, and names with an envelope next to them
>   have new messages.

Comment: Is there a more simple way to implement a ping-pong mechanism without using STOMP?